# Difficulties in calling ajax from joomla 2.5 module

Tags: php, ajax, module

Hi i am having problem to call another file by ajax from module.As i don't want to make a component to call it for ajax from module, so what i am thinking is calling index.php file from ajax passing a task variable and catching that variable in module main php file and returning data back to same module js ajax code. How much fruitful is this way and how do i return json data in best way? And any security risks?

Edit: this way i am calling ajax

```
$.ajax({                    
        cache:false,                
        url:"<?php echo JURI::current(); ?>",
        type: 'GET',
        data:
        {              
           ajax: "true",                    
           sid: (Math.floor(Math.random() * 900000) + 100000)            
        }, ....
```

And in module's main php file -

```
$task = JRequest::getVar('ajax');
if($task=="true")
{    
  //for test 
  echo "hurray"; exit; 
}
```

If there are best error free ways then let me know.

Comment: If AJAX doesn't return anything sensitive data you musn't be worry

Comment: You say your module is going to be commercial and therefore available for people to use on their own sites. Is this module going to be for Joomla 2.5 only? Cause I would strongly suggest you do not use `JRequest` as it's deprecated

Comment: yes say it's only for joomla 2.5 right now. But how fruitful is the url setting `url:"<?php echo JURI::current(); ?>",` in ajax call. Are there any drawbacks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nowadays, the simplest way to work with Ajax from modules is implementing **com_ajax**. You can just install it and talk with com_ajax from any other extension.

Furthermore, you are working fully integrated with Joomla API, and you are in a far better position than installing a raw index.php (besides a security risk, there are measures that restrict this raw access e.g. .htaccess, therefore you would have to deactivate them. In conclusion, not recommended)

**Joomla! Ajax Interface**
https://github.com/Joomla-Ajax-Interface/component

It's included in Joomla 3.2 and superior, and it's installable on Joomla 2.5.

**Hello Ajax World**
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gyc1qwaUQoY&list=PLSwFVRVZ3joTo3InkU_FT65_AK8dQiyZ4&index=40

Comment: I do know joomla core classes and use and i can implement com_ajax but my that module is a commercial module which many users will install, so it not looks good to tell them install com_ajax too.

Comment: You can include in your module installer a script to install com_ajax. It's the best option to avoid a support nightmare caused by distributing a raw index.php.

Comment: Can you please elaborate bit more about how and why a raw index.php affects module's json datatype ajax call.my simple ajax call i mentioned works well but not tested all the way.

Comment: A raw index.php can work perfectly well in your site. But it's not a standard practice. Thus, if you copy the file in some directory, a hardened .htaccess most probably block the access from a call.

Comment: Does com_ajax works in 2.5 now https://github.com/Joomla-Ajax-Interface/component?

Comment: Yes, in fact, now this repo only supports Joomla v2.5 (since com_ajax is official and included in Joomla v3)

Comment: It's look like i will create a package by http://docs.joomla.org/Package , including my module and com_ajax component.

Comment: Found inconsistency: i am getting fb/twitter feed which are already in json, so is it appropriate to have it encoded again in com_ajax ? - `JResponse::setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json', true); echo json_encode($results);`. for this i was not getting data in ajax call.So is added only `echo $results;` in com_ajax removing above 2 lines and added `dataType: json` in jquery ajax call & i am getting data now. are there any drawbacks for that & what else to do in case of fb/twitter feed ?

Comment: It's better if you publish a new question with full details.

Comment: Yes, in a Pakcage you include everything inside.

Comment: It's look like even if i have multiple same module instances, module helper file takes module parameter values from first module instance not from other instances i desire as i have different param values across all those same module instances. Any way to achieve wat i want?